# DOMDocument::load - PHP - Getting attribute value

Tags: php, xml, excel, dom

I am struggling to get the value of 3 from the `ss:ExpandedColumnCount="3"` in

```
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="3" ss:ExpandedRowCount="2" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="65" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">cat</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">dog</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">horse</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ve</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">as</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">fs</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
 <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ve</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">as</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">fs</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
```

I am using DOMDocument::load in PHP using an XLS file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: *(tipp)* You could use PHPExcel to work with MS Office XML.

Comment: Show us the code you have written.

Comment: This snippet is part of the Excel2003 XML format... PHPExcel can indeed read these files, although I haven't yet finished coding up the Writer yet.

Answer (score 3):

Load the document

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('YourExcel.xml');
```

and then either do

```
echo $dom->documentElement->getAttribute('ExpandedColumnCount');
```

or use XPath

```
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo $xp->evaluate('string(/Table/@ExpandedColumnCount)');
```

Both will return 3.