# How to retrieve attribute of root element of DOMDocument?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DOMDocument::load - PHP - Getting attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757587/domdocumentload-php-getting-attribute-value)

I use the following code:

```
$str = '<a href="some_link">text</a>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($str);
```

I want to obtain the value of root element of `$str`.
In this example `"some_link"` should be returned. In real case `$str` is read from file.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$dom->documentElement->getAttribute('%yourAttrName%');
```