# how do you get the id and class of the elements parsed with php

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DOMDocument::load - PHP - Getting attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757587/domdocumentload-php-getting-attribute-value)

I have many div tags pulled from a string through php, each of them having a unique id and a subjective class. I am trying to get the id and class of each of the divs but am not too sure how I would do this.

HTML:

```
<div id='x1y1' class = 'classname'></div><div id = 'x2y1' class = 'classname1'>
```

so far I have tried

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML($boardDataStripSlashes);
$elements = $html->getElementsByTagName('div');
```

but have not been able to find anything on how to get the actual id's and classes of the selected elements.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php

Comment: I feel really dumb right now, scoured google for a good 4 hours before asking.. thank you

Comment: It happens to the best of us. Just [join the PHP channel here on site](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php). You will get better feedback ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`DOMElement::getAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) to retrieve attributes of elements.

```
foreach($elements as $element) { 
  $id = $element->getAttribute('id');
  $className = $element->getAttribute('class');
  // ...
}
```